# Port forwarding issues trying to run a docker container

Tags: macos, performance, tcp, docker, boot2docker

I am new to docker and nowhere near a networking expert, but I am seeing some strangeness when trying to run a docker container instance (right word?). I am running docker on OSX and set it up using the documentation found here: http://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide

Everything seems to have gone along fine, then I set up the port forwarding rules via these lines:

```
for i in {49000..49900}; 
do VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port$i,tcp,,$i,,$i";
done
```

I can confirm the boot2docker VM instance by checking the configuration within the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager->Network->Adapter 1->Port Forwarding with the OSX.

I then run this command to get the container.

```
docker run -d -P dockerhub.emory.edu/ecoi_trunk:2
```

I do a "docker ps" and get this info.

```
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                     CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
 f20bfefa2e97        dockerhub.emory.edu/ecoi_trunk:2   "/usr/sbin/apachectl   18 seconds    ago      Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:49153->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49154->80/tcp   cranky_einstein
```

However, when I run an "lsof -i :49153" I see nothing is listening. I also can't reach the container via the "l****host:49153" in my browser. It just hangs.

What's strange is if I explicitly set the port (rather than allowing docker to assign one) via the following command:

```
 docker run -d -p 49000:80 dockerhub.emory.edu/ecoi_trunk:2
```

It seems to work (lsof -i:49000 displays a TCP LISTEN), and I can confirm it's listening and the container is reachable via "l****host:49000". However, it's extremely slow. I'm not sure if either are related, but would welcome any tips or thoughts.

Comment: I've researched it a bit further. It definitely seems to have an issue with the 49153 and 49154 ports, which are the first two that docker assigns.

Comment: Try using `sudo lsof -i :49153` - docker runs as root. `sudo netstat -tunlp` sould also show you the TCP listen by docker-proxy, too. Generally speaking things like this are problems with your app inside your container (just container, not container instance :)) - do you have application level logging that you can look at to troubleshoot further? What happens when you `telnet localhost 49153`?